# CDFs on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, canvas, graph, wolfram-cdf

My math professor wants to be able to generate interactive graphs (i.e. the kind you can generate with a CDF) on an iPad. Users should effectively be able to do everything they can do on a computer using the CDF player on an iPad, using whatever the web browser can do. I was thinking something along the lines of a canvas element, but does anyone know if there's a native client for the iPad? If not, is there some way of compiling Mathematica graphics code into something Safari or Chrome could understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best (only?) reliable current information comes from the [Wolfram CDF FAQ](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/):

> **Is CDF Player available for iPad?**
>
> The iPad is an important part of our CDF strategy. Contact us for more
>   details about when CDF support for this platform becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

This took longer than expected, but this is now available:

http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/11/16/launching-wolfram-player-for-ios/